# php/ajax - {"success":{"title":"Message Sent"}}

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

I've never used ajax before but from what I can tell that's the solution to my problem, basically I'm using a PHPmailer form on indk.org/contact.html and when you hit submit it displays a new window (taking you away from the website nav) with `{"success":{"title":"Message Sent"}}` shown

How do I stop this happening, or at the very least, have a message sent confirmation appear on the webpage itself, want to avoid taking people off site as much as I can as it's a personal portfolio.

Welcome any aid! Thanks :) D

```
    <?php 

    require '../_lib/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    // CONFIG YOUR FIELDS
    //============================================================
    $name =     filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email =    filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $formMessage =  filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    // CONFIG YOUR EMAIL MESSAGE
    //============================================================
    $message = '<p>The following request was sent from: </p>';
    $message .= '<p>Name: ' . $name . '</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Email: ' . $email . '</p>';
    $message .= '<p>Message: ' . $formMessage .'</p>';

    // CONFIG YOUR MAIL SERVER
    //============================================================
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();                                    // Enable SMTP     authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mailout.one.com';                // Specify main and backup server (this is a fake name for the use of this example)             

    $mail->Username = 'dk@indk.org';                  // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'XXX';                         // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'SSL';                          // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted                                   
    $mail->Port = 587;                        

    $mail->From = 'dk@indk.org';
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email,$name);
    $mail->addAddress('dk@indk.org', $name);  // Add a recipient

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                               // Set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Contact request';
    $mail->Body    = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
   $data['error']['title'] = 'Message could not be sent.';
   $data['error']['details'] = 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

$data['success']['title'] = 'Message Sent, click back to return to indk.org';


echo json_encode($data);


?>



$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    $('#contact-form').validate({
        // Override to submit the form via ajax
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#contact-panel').portlet({
                refresh:true
            });
            $.ajax({
                 type:$(form).attr('method'),
                 url: $(form).attr('action'),
                 data: $(form).serialize(),
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                   //Set your Success Message
                   clearForm("Thank you for Contacting Us! We will be in touch");
                 },
                 error: function(err){
                    $('#contact-panel').portlet({
                        refresh:false,
                        //Set your ERROR Message
                        error:"We could not send your message, Please try Again"
                    });
                 }
            });
            return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax
        }
    });
    function clearForm(msg){
        $('#contact-panel').html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">'+msg+'</div>');
    }

    $('#contact-panel').portlet({
        onRefresh: function() {
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to add the relevant code to the question

Comment: Why not just redirect to "email_sent.html" from "mail.php"?

Comment: @DaveChen that could work, didn't think about that... it was late and I was fading haha! Thank you :)

Comment: @jiml added the code :)

Comment: The javascript (ajax) code as well ^^

Comment: @jiml added the js

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either way. You can use a simple bootstrap pop-up to show the confirmation or as you said you can use AJAX.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of the bootstrap pop-up? I've never used AJAX before so this is new to me! But keen to learn as I figure it out :)

Comment: Sure. Here is the best and easy tutorial regarding bootstrap pop up(i.e. modal). http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp